# Attach or embed node add form to a view

Tags: 7, views, forms, blocks, ajax

I want to attach or embed a node form to a view so that when a user submits the form, the view below the form will be updated in realtime via ajax. The form will be shown above the view. My views block name is **Statuses Stream**.

I tried [formblock module](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) and putting the form in the header section of my view using views ui, but after submit, it was redirecting to the node created page.

Then I tried [Advanced Form Block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb). I created a form using AFB module. It is submitting the form with ajax, but it is not updating the view in the realtime.

I have just tried the [Ajax Form Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_form_entity) module. It is submitting and updating via ajax, but I cannot find a way to attach a view with it. However, in its settings, I can select a view mode. I need a little more flexibility.

How to Attach or embed node form to a view so that it submits via ajax and updates the view in realtime? I am open to any solution programmatically or through a module. Better if done programmatically because it will give more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ld take it from the other side: Attach a view to a node form.

First I tried it with the built-in node form. But this turned out to be quite a hassle. Instead I built a small custom form and created new nodes programmatically. Ajax submit. View refreshed. Happy, happy.

Here comes the code for a custom module. Presuming a fresh D7 standard installation.

**Info file**

```
name = MYMODULE
description = Provides cool stuff.
core = 7.x
package = Custom
dependencies[] = views
```

**Module file**

First provide a view.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_api() {

  return [
    'api' => 3,
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_default_views() {

  $view = new view();
  $view->name = 'nodes';
  $view->description = '';
  $view->tag = 'default';
  $view->base_table = 'node';
  $view->human_name = 'Nodes';
  $view->core = 7;
  $view->api_version = '3.0';
  $view->disabled = FALSE;

  /* Display: Master */
  $handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
  $handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Nodes';
  $handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
  $handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
  $handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
  $handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
  $handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
  $handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
  $handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
  $handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
  $handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
  /* Field: Content: Title */
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
  $handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
  /* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
  $handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
  $handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
  $handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
  $handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';

  /* Display: Block */
  $handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');

  $views[$view->name] = $view;
  return $views;
}
```

Then do the form.

```
/**
 * Provide a form.
 */
function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['wrapper'] = [
    '#type'       => 'container',
    '#attributes' => [
      'id' => 'mywrapper',
    ],
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['node_form'] = [
    '#type'  => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Add article'),
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['node_form']['node_title'] = [
    '#type'     => 'textfield',
    '#title'    => t('Article title'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['submit'] = [
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    '#value'  => t('Save'),
    '#submit' => ['MYMODULE_form_submit'],
    '#ajax'   => [
      'callback' => 'MYMODULE_MYCALLBACK',
      'wrapper'  => 'mywrapper',
    ],
  ];

  $form['wrapper']['view_display'] = [
    // view machine name && display/block name
    '#markup' => views_embed_view('nodes', 'block'),
  ];

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Do some validation.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Better do some validation.
  // Here or via #element_validate.
  // @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#element_validate
}

/**
 * Form submit. Node creation.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  global $user;
  $node = new stdClass();

  $node->type     = 'article';
  $node->title    = $form_state['values']['node_title'];
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->uid      = $user->uid;

  node_object_prepare($node);
  node_save($node);

  // Empty out title field on rebuild.
  $form_state['input']['node_title'] = '';

  // Rebuild form.
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * Ajax callback to return the whole wrapper.
 */
function MYMODULE_MYCALLBACK($form, &$form_state) {

  return $form['wrapper'];
}
```

I've put it on a sample page to see it in action.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {

  $items['example/form'] = [
    'title'            => 'Example Form',
    'description'      => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => ['MYMODULE_form'],
    'access arguments' => ['create article content'],
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: I have few questions. 1. To change content type I just have to change here `$node->type     = 'article';` right? 2. In the view above, I do not see content type article. Why? 3. Will this form work as the node form does? I mean the settings in content type article will still have its effects? Like fields or enabling disabling text formats etc. 4. Regarding the `'id' => 'mywrapper'` and `'wrapper' => 'mywrapper'` Can I change it to anything? 5. What I am supposed to replace MYCALLBACK with here `'callback' => 'MYMODULE_MYCALLBACK',`

Comment: 6. In hook menu, what I have understood, example/form is the url where users will see this whole thing. right? What if I do not want to show it on a page. Instead show it in a block which I can put anywhere on the website.

Comment: 7. How to hide the title? I do not want users to insert and see the title field

Comment: @Umair - You can render the form everywhere you want. In a block, in a template. As you need. The page is only for demo purpose. Then, please, post a separate question for every problem that persists.

Comment: OK. Please atleast tell me what should put instead of MYCALLBACK?

Comment: @Umair - The callback can be named anything you want. You could also simply leave it as it is now.

Comment: It is working but it is only showing title field. Where is the body field? I tried to add the body field, similar to how you added title field, but it is not showing.

Comment: @Umair - Please ask a separate question and provide sample code.

Comment: See this [Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239269/how-to-add-existing-fields-to-a-custom-form)